# Самостоятельный перезапуск приложения. asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Как перезапустить asp.net core приложение в методе контроллера?

Есть приложение, которое считывает конфигурацию из базы данных при запуске. Администратор вводит новые настройки приложения, сохраняет их в бд и указывает, когда приложение должно быть перезапущено для принятия новых настроек (или сразу перезапускает). Как это провернуть, если приложение работает в iis?

Comment: Просто интересно - это какие такие настройки требуют перезапуска приложения?

Comment: @tym32167 конфигурация клиентов Identity Server

Comment: Принял. Не работал с этим, но почитать было интересно, спасибо

Comment: Сделайте `Environment.Exit` и след. запрос к вашему сервису его должен бы поднять. По крайней мере, в отладочных целях у меня такое работает стабильно.

Comment: https://github.com/avtc/GracefullShutdown